# Display database row based on option tag value PHP HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, html-select

I have done the implementation in my HTML code through PHP where the  tag has the  tag filled with values from a specific column from my database. (E.g) Column is "id" and the  content are the actual id numbers. In my case 1,2,3,4.

Code here:

```
$sql = "SELECT id from Cliente";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
   echo "<select name='fecha'>";
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {                      
        echo "<option value='".$row['id']."'>" . $row['id'] . "</option>";
       }
   echo "</select>";
```

What I want to do now is based on the selected option (selected id on other words), to display the whole row of content that of course includes that id.

Does anyone know how I can do this? How I need to change my code? I am a bit confused.

Let's say I choose id="3", based on the content of the image I would like all the info from that row to display.

IMAGE OF DATABASE FOR EXTRA INFORMATION

[image: Image Database]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this query instead of the one you have

```
SELECT id, nombres, apellido1, apellido2, direccion FROM Cliente ORDER BY id
```

Then you'll have access to `$row['nombres']`, `$row['apellido1']` and the rest as well as `$row['id']` in your `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))` loop.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. The problem with that is that I have the "while" is inside the <select> tag. I can not display the table with the desired value here. I need it to be outside the <select>tag. Is there any recommendation you have? Thanks!